# Passing response data in feature file cucumber

Tags: rest, cucumber, bdd, feature-file

I have 2 APIs
One API will give a 5 digit code
Other API will validate that 5 digit code

Currently Iam writing feature files for both APIs
In order to test these APIs in cucumber , I have written feature files for both.

So how can I pass the response received from first API in the feature file of the second API , Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Scenario of both the APIs are same feature file or in different feature file? Which framework are you using eg. Karate/RestAssured?

Comment: Both are in different feature files , Iam using cucumber framework , and rest assured util to call the APIs

Comment: Are you using Cucumber in Java, JavaScript, Ruby --- which programming language?

Comment: Cucumber in java